# Change 'This product is out of stock' message in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, messages

When I list a product as **out of stock** and try to add it to my basket I get the message '**This product is out of stock**'.

I'd like to **change this message** to '***This product is currently out of stock, please call store for updates***'.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done in **Magento 2**?

Comment: Did you try with translation?

Comment: I have, didn't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than overwrite `vendor/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv` as suggested in @Pankaj Bhope answer you should create your own translation file in `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/i18n/en_US.csv` and add your translation to it:

```
"This product is out of stock.","This product is currently out of stock, please call store for updates."
```

If you don't follow this approach and overwrite Magento's core functionality directly at `vendor/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv` your changes will be lost when you next update Magento2 to avail of new features or security updates.

Also english US is the default locale on a Magento2 installation, but if you've set a different locale at *Stores -> Configuration -> General* you will need to change the file name from `en_US.csv` to match your locale, `en_GB.csv` for the UK for instance.

You can find more information here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

1) Modify **vendor/module-catalog-invertory/i18n/en_US.csv**

2) There are two entries of this message **"This product is out of stock"**

3) Change to **"This product is currently out of stock, please call store for updates".**

4) Clear Static contents.

5) Deploy using the cli command.

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

6) Now check again. If this does not work, you can directly change the message by overriding the classes but I will not recommend doing that.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Just to say I did not have to redeploy static content. It worked simply by updating that csv file.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help :)

Comment: if you follow this approach your changes will be lost when you update your Magento2 store, the recommended approach is to add your own _translation dictionary_ to your theme, as described in the [Magento2 Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)

Comment: Never update vendor files.