# In magento 2 how to change a stock availability for 'out of stock' products in frontend

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock

In Magento 2 how to change a stock availability for 'out of stock' products in frontend (category listing and product detail page).
I don't want to override a template file. I want to change a custom message instead of the 'Out of stock' stock availability message in frontend.

> layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Vendor\LowStockNotification\Block\Product" after="product.info.addtocart" template="Vendor_LowStockNotification::custom_file.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> layout/catalog_categoy_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_LowStockNotification::custom_file.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> custom_file.phtml

```
<?php  
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$showStockStatus  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('lowstocknotification/low_stock_notification/stock_status/show_stock_status');
$customMessage = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('lowstocknotification/low_stock_notification/stock_status/custom_status');
?>
<!-- custom Stock -->
<input type="hidden" class="show-stock-status" name="showstatus" id="show_stock_status" value="<?php echo $showStockStatus ?>">
<input type="hidden" class="custom-status" name="showstatus" id="custom_status" value="<?php echo $customMessage ?>">
<!-- custom Stock -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {

    var showStatus = $('.show-stock-status').val();
    var customMessage = $('.custom-status').val();
    if(showStatus == 1 && !empty(customMessage)){
        $(".stock.unavailable").text(customMessage);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please check this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163906/change-this-product-is-out-of-stock-message-in-magento-2

Comment: I need to change a custom stock status  programmatically @Mayur Sisodiya

Comment: But you don't want to override the file then how will you achieve it?

Comment: I just search for plugin or observer event otherwise override a js file but i don't want to override a template file @MayurSisodiya

Comment: @divyasekar Please check and update me.

Comment: You can try CSV translation in your theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You Can change this message using jQuery text() Method. you call this line when your page load into your jQuery file.

```
$(".stock.unavailable").text("Your Custom Text");
```

Comment: i was  set a text() with jquery on page load its changed to custom text only for simple products its worked but when change an attribute in the configurable product its not a  custom stock message

Comment: I posted my code in the above question

Comment: you need to add code into this file Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js   -> _OnClick: function that file is responsible it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than overwrite `vendor/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv` you should create your own translation file in `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/i18n/en_US.csv` and add your translation to it:

"Out of stock.","This product is currently out of stock"
If you don't follow this approach and overwrite Magento's core functionality directly at `vendor/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv` your changes will be lost when you next update Magento2 to avail of new features or security updates.

Also english US is the default locale on a Magento2 installation, but if you've set a different locale at Stores -> Configuration -> General you will need to change the file name from `en_US.csv` to match your locale, `en_GB.csv` for the UK for instance.

> You can find more information here:
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html